# $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(f_k) \leq \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(g_k)$

Tags: real-analysis

> **True or False:** If $|f_k| \leq g_k$ for all $k \geq 1$, and the limits of the sequences $f_k$ and $g_k$ exist and are equal to $f$ and $g$ respectively, then it follows that $f \leq g$

My answer: True.

**Proof Attempt:**

Let $ε > 0$ be given. Then since  $f_k \to f$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $k > N$: $|f_k - f| < ε$

Similarly, $g_k \to g$, there exists a positive integer $M$ such that for all $k > M$, we have $|g_k - g| < ε$.

Also $f - ε \leq f_k $

Let $K = \max(N, M)$, since $|f_k| \leq g_k$, then

$f - ε \leq f_k \leq g_k \leq g + ε$ for all $k > K$.

Taking the limit as $k $ approaches infinity, we get

$f - ε \leq f \leq g \leq g + ε$
$ \ \Rightarrow f \leq g$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(f_k) \leq \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(g_k)$, as desired.

Does it look correct?

Comment: @JMP leftover from previous version of the proof. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to go through $\epsilon$ in this case.

Your inequality implies that
$$
-g_k \leq f_k \leq g_k, \quad \mbox{for all}~k.
$$
Taking limits---which is valid since $f_k \to f, g_k \to g$---you have
$$
-g \leq f \leq g.
$$

---

A fair point is made that perhaps you are not able to assume that inequalities are preserved under limits.

You have $f_k \to f, g_k \to g$ as $k \to \infty$ and moreover $f_k \leq g_k$ for all $k$.

Thus, for all $k$, one has
$$
f-g = (f - f_k) + (g_k - g) + f_k - g_k \leq (f - f_k) + (g_k - g)
$$
On the other hand, if $\epsilon > 0$, you must have for all $k$ large enough that the righthand side is less than $\epsilon$.
Thus, you conclude
$$
f - g \leq \epsilon, 
$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, $f \leq g$.

Comment: would this be still be true if $f_k \leq g_k$ instead of $|f_k| \leq g_k$ for all $k$?

Comment: Is there an example where this would fail?

Comment: The OP's question is does limits preserve inequalities. You "proved" it by saying yes limits preserve inequalities.

Comment: Fair point---I read the question and discussion quickly. I have added more detail, providing direct proof rather than a contradiction argument as in Robert's answer below.

Comment: And to answer @WebTyper, yes, you only need the one-sided inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof doesn't work.  When you take the limit as $n \to \infty$, you are assuming what you're trying to prove.

Here's a proof.  Assume toward a contradiction that $f \gt g$.  Then set $\varepsilon = \dfrac{f-g}{2}$.  Choose $N$ such that $k \gt N \Rightarrow (\vert g-g_k \vert \lt \varepsilon \land \vert f-f_k \vert \lt \varepsilon)$.  Then we would have $g_k \lt \dfrac{f+g}{2} \lt f_k$, contrary to our assumption that $f_k \leq g_k$.  This contradiction shows that our assumption that $f \gt g$ must be false, so by trichotomy, $f \leq g$.

The proof holds as long as $\forall k~(f_k \leq g_k)$.  In fact, the proof holds as long as this inequality holds for infinitely many $k$.